# per occurrence deductible vs co-pay

Tags: united-states, health-insurance

I'm comparing insurances to select my benefits. One says the outpatient surgery 
facility fee is $xxx/visit, while the other says $0 coinsurance but has a $yyy "Hospital per occurrence deductible." Is a per-occurrence deductible a fancy way of saying "co-pay"? Is there a difference between a "per visit" and a "per occurrence" when it comes to hospital fees?

Comment: I've added the "united-states" tag, on the assumption you are in the US.  If not, please indicate where you are - this is going to be completely location specific.

Answer (score 1):

There likely isn't a difference between visit and occurrence, but that would be in the fine-print.

If the "per-occurrence deductible" is unaffected by your plan deductible then yes it would seem like that's the same thing as a co-pay. You would have to check the plan, but I would assume that the "per-occurrence deductible" still goes towards your plan's deductible while a co-pay would not.

The best thing to do is to call them and make them explain and give you the exact location in the fine-print that applies to your questions.